# Return 1 in non main function

Tags: c

I am currently learning c and i have a confusion regarding return:

```
int factorial (int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial (n -1);
}
```

In the above recursive code in the last call when n is 1, will the return 1 will return the integer value one or error in execution like in main. I had this confusion because return 1 is treated differently in main and in a function called by main...

Comment: You can return `1` from any function returning `int`, even `main`. (The return value from `main` may be interpreted in some way by the *operating system*, but any legal `int` can be returned from the *program*'s point of view).

Comment: 1. Please remove the C++ tag if this question is about C. 2. What makes you think that returning `1` is an error?

Comment: How would any function doing some calculation be able to return `1` (or any non-zero value) if it was considered to be an error? That the return values for `main` are zero for okay and a small positive number for an error is just a *convention* really.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about functions and return values. Reread the chapter dealing with functions in your C textbook.

Comment: Well, a cosine of 0 is exactly 1 and a function calculating this cosine _must_ return one, but it certainly isn't treated as an error.

Comment: "or error in execution like in main" - The `main()` function has specific rules, unrelated to *your* functions. The C standard specifies three values for `main()` return, then blanket covers everything else: `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` (both represent an implementation-defined *successful* termination status), and `EXIT_FAILURE` (represents an implementation-defined *unsuccessful* termination status). That `EXIT_FAILURE` is typically `1` is common, but *not* mandated by the standard. Anything else is entirely up to the implementation. All that is *unrelated* to *your* functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the `return 1` return the integer value one or error in execution like in main?

`return 1` returns the integer value `1` from *any* function declared to return `int`, *even if that function happens to be `int main()`*.

A non-zero return value from `main()` is *interpreted* (by the execution environment, e.g. the shell) to indicate an error in execution. That happens to be the *semantic* of the return value of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement will return the value in the parameter of the return statement and it must be of type as declared in the function. The meaning of the value depends on the interpretation. The return value of the main function can be interpreted as success or error codes. Sometimes in other functions too.

Answer (score 0):

`return 1` means returning 1 - whether it's in the `main` function or in any other function.

The interpretation of a function's return-value is made by **the calling function**.

In the case of `main`, since no function in the code should be calling it, the interpretation of 1 as *error in execution* is made (or more precisely, can be made) by whoever executes the program.